# Using crystal report in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I tried to install crystal report, but It is blocked at the step of displaying a message:

> error 1935 an error occurred during the installation of assembly component hresult 0x80070bc9

I have a 64bit system.

Comment: you have to provide more info plz. what version are you installing?

Comment: Provide screenshots. Also provide information on what version you are installing. We could also do with knowing more information on your OS.

Comment: it is crystal_report 13.0.4 and It's windows 7, 64bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the problem in my case was because it was missing installing the .net framework on the client computer.

I hope it helps